# Test global effect of the categorical predictors and their interactions in GLM

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

I run a Gamma GLM using 3 categorical predictors:

1. `Year` - with 4 classes
2. `Organ` - with 3 classes
3. `Site` - with 3 classes

My model is:

```
GLM <- glm(biom ~ fyear + organ + site + fyear:organ + fyear:site + organ:site,
           data = data, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
```

The summary(GLM) gives me this (3 coefficients are not defined because of singularities):

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        3.34408    0.39101   8.552 7.89e-14 ***
fyear2            -0.55195    0.29480  -1.872  0.06382 .  
fyear3             0.65445    0.29480   2.220  0.02847 *  
fyear4            -0.20425    0.29616  -0.690  0.49186    
organleaf          1.62266    0.39846   4.072 8.80e-05 ***
organshoot         2.64728    0.33840   7.823 3.40e-12 ***
siteL              1.01485    0.53400   1.900  0.05999 .  
siteo              0.41056    0.52632   0.780  0.43703    
fyear2:organleaf   0.03728    0.29480   0.126  0.89959    
fyear3:organleaf  -0.03519    0.29480  -0.119  0.90520    
fyear4:organleaf  -2.03455    0.30021  -6.777 6.34e-10 ***
fyear2:organshoot       NA         NA      NA       NA    
fyear3:organshoot       NA         NA      NA       NA    
fyear4:organshoot       NA         NA      NA       NA    
fyear2:siteL       0.78444    0.36105   2.173  0.03195 *  
fyear3:siteL      -0.01524    0.36105  -0.042  0.96641    
fyear4:siteL       0.28738    0.37216   0.772  0.44166    
fyear2:siteo       1.04849    0.36105   2.904  0.00445 ** 
fyear3:siteo       0.08768    0.36105   0.243  0.80858    
fyear4:siteo       0.71053    0.36105   1.968  0.05159 .  
organleaf:siteL   -1.41692    0.48655  -2.912  0.00435 ** 
organshoot:siteL  -1.59445    0.48655  -3.277  0.00140 ** 
organleaf:siteo   -0.86975    0.47763  -1.821  0.07133 .  
organshoot:siteo  -1.30913    0.47763  -2.741  0.00715 **
```

Do you know how can I determine the "global" effect of each factor and interaction (e.g., the p-values and F's of the factor `organ` or of the interaction `organ:site`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You won't get an "$F\,$" test statistic, because this is a non-normal GLM.)

However, you can test a categorical variable or the interaction as a whole.  This is called a 'simultaneous test'.  To do this, you fit a nested model by dropping the variable in question.  Then you perform a nested model test.  Since you have a Gamma GLM, that would be a likelihood ratio test and the test statistic would be distributed as chi-squared.  Nonetheless, you would get a test statistic and a p-value.

To test the `organ:site` interaction in `R`, e.g., you would do:

```
nested.model = glm(biom~fyear+organ+site+fyear:organ+fyear:site,  # removed organ:site
                   data=data, family=Gamma(link = "log"))
anova(nested.model, GLM, test="LRT")
```

Some other notes:  Be aware that the test of a 'main effect' (i.e., `organ`) in the context of a model that includes interaction terms that contain the variable in question only tests if the levels of that variable differ within the reference level of the interacting variable.  If that is meaningful in your case (it could be, but often isn't), you can use the procedure I describe above.  If it isn't meaningful, the question itself isn't meaningful unless all the encompasing interaction terms are sufficiently non-significant that they can be dropped entirely from the model.  Then the model without any interaction terms would become the new 'full model' from which you could fit nested models to test those variables.

Also, my guess is that the `year` variable can be considered an equal-interval continuous variable.  I would probably set the first year equal to `0` and the remaining years `1, 2, 3`.  That would most likely give you a better model and eliminate the singularity.

Comment: If you do the anova(nested.model, GLM, test="LRT") it gives you Pr(>Chi) 0.01182 *
Which means that the interaction has a significant effect on the model. But how this result can be presented on a paper? e.g. The "organ x site" interction found to be significant (Pr(>Chi)<0.05)...?

Comment: In addition, drop1(GLM, test = "Chi") gives the same results but just for the interactions. So my real problem is to be able to do the same for the main effects also.

Comment: @Geo, thank you for registering your account. In a paper, to present your result in 'journal form', I would write, "The test of the ORGAN x SITE interaction was significant at the .05 level ($\chi^2$ = 4.2, df=4, p=0.012)." (However, I don't quite understand that result: the p-value is awfully low for a chi-squared of 4.2 on 4df.) Note that `drop1()` is a wrapper for the process I describe here.

Comment: gung thank you. This doesn't seem to apply for the main effects though.

Comment: @Geo, as I discussed, if the interaction is significant (as it is), the question of the main effect is nonsensical.

Comment: Ok i know this. But my question is if there is a way to have p-values also for the main effects. For instance, when you perform gamma GLM in SPSS there is a table (Tests of Model effects) that gives you the Wald Chi-square, df and p-values for all main effects and interactions.

Comment: Do you have any idea what that SPSS output means, @Geo? I'm not sure I do. If it's just the equivalence of the levels of the variable w/i the reference level of the interacting variable, you can do what I described above. Otherwise, I have no idea.

Comment: No I don't know exactly what SPSS output means. It seems that the solution you presented is the closest i can get. Thank you once again @gung.